# gitlab cannot pull or clone project

Tags: gitlab

I got this message error when do this command git clone https://project.gitlab.cct/user/testproject.git Initialized empty Git repository in /root/testproject/.git/ error: The requested URL returned error: 401 Unauthorized while accessing https://project.gitlab.cct/user/testproject.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed

This project is set private and although I were granted permission to access this project (joined), someone help me to turn off authorization for private project or appear a password prompt to access

Thank you!

Comment: Have you imported your public SSH key into GitLab?

Comment: Thank for reply Amadan. I find out the problems, because of old version of git, I add username to url in .git/config.

Comment: Thanks Jin for this thread and your reply. i am even not aware of the old urls but finally figure it out. this is for those who don't know how to add username in url https://USERNAME@project.gitlab.cct/user/testproject.git. @jin correct me if i am wrong. 

i was getting this error on git version 1.7.1 and unable to update to latest version as shared hosting so finally have included username in url.